# Looking for a list of tools/add-ins for ArcGIS Explorer

Tags: add-ons, arcgis-explorer

I'm hoping to compile a list of [add-ins](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/1500/sdk/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Customizing_ArcGIS_Explorer/000200000020000000/) & resources for [ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/key-features.html).  I intend to install it at home, and apparently, there are a number of server feeds out there that can significantly augment the capabilities of this **free** ESRI software (IMS/WMS servers, toolbox items, etc, etc).

I thought many of you might be interested in having access to such a compilation as well, especially since it's a free software.  I'm quite anxious to see what's out there!!

Try your best to give at least a brief description of the add-in/server feed you post in your answers.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google finds [AGX Social - Post your map image on Twitter & Facebook](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c001a7f17cc644b4a00a40a9b66542b1) at arcgis.com.

But then, when I click on the [add-in tag](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?t=content&q=tags:add-in) at the bottom of that page, I don't see anything, which seems kind of strange - obviously there is a page with that tag.

**Update:**

If I set the Show option to "All Content" ...
[image]

Then click the "add-in" tag on the page, I get lots of [results](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?t=content&q=tags:add-in).

`http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?t=content&q=tags:add-in`

I guess "All content" means the universe, whereas "Web Content" means stuff not hosted at Arcgis.com.

Comment: I get the same result.  Perhaps the URL was changed, or the link is broken?

Comment: @Dano User error, see updated answer.

Comment: +1 & +1 @ Kirk - There are quite a few of them - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Explorer is also available online now

http://explorer.arcgis.com/?open=153c17de00914039bb28f6f6efe6d322

[image]

If you want to customise your maps you need to have a global esri account.

http://blogs.esri.com/Info/blogs/arcgisexplorerblog/archive/2009/08/19/sample-add-ins-at-arcgis-explorer-labs.aspx

Comment: I was aware that you could use an online interface. My thinking, in all honesty, was that I could expext better performance from having installed directly on my computer. This raises some questions for me: 1.Are there no other resources besides the ones at the link you posted?  From what I read, ESRI does not limit developers from selling their add-ons.  I assumed this meant that there might be other sources for tools and base map servers due to the "profit factor" 2.If not, then this is a bad question. That said, should it not be deleted? Your houghts/feedback would be appreciated Mapperz.